# Tfs project creation results in error: TF400930: Field 'System.ExternalLinkCount' is defined multiple times

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

I have recently upgraded an on-premises Team Foundation Server from Tfs 2015 to Tfs2015.Update3 (14.102.25423.0)
The upgrade was completed and all other functionality seems to work as usual.
A day or so ago I attempted to create a new Tfs project (TFVC) and that resulted in an error.

When I look at the application tier log files, I see the following:

```
[10:31:30.153] Executing step: Create the Team Project.
[10:31:30.167]   Executing step: 'Create the Team Project.' WorkItemTracking.CreateTeamProject (4 of 13)
[10:31:30.183]   Getting process template.
[10:31:31.463]   Refreshing server caches.
[10:31:31.463]   Importing work item link types.
[10:31:32.180]   Importing work item types
[10:31:33.727]   Importing work item types
[10:31:34.413]   [Error] TF400930: Field 'System.ExternalLinkCount' is defined multiple times with different field definitions. Correct the field definition and try again.
[10:31:34.507]   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.LegacyValidationException: TF400930: Field 'System.ExternalLinkCount' is defined multiple times with different field definitions. Correct the field definition and try again.
[10:31:34.507]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.ProvisioningService.InternalImportWorkItemTypesOrGlobalWorkflows(IVssRequestContext requestContext, Int32 projectId, String methodologyName, IEnumerable`1 typeElements, ProvisioningActionType actionType, InternalSchemaType schemaType, Boolean overwrite, ProvisioningImportEventsCallback importEventCallback)
```

We are unfortunately making use of a customized template (which is based on the Scrum template) and it is exactly this template that causes the error.
When creating a new Tfs project (TFVC) based on the standard Scrum or Agile templates it works fine.

I downloaded the customized scrum template in question and did a grep search on “**System.ExternalLinkCount**”.
When I look at the fields they do seem to be of the same type.
Any ideas or suggestion why it is acting up in this way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the field definition from these work items, it's a standard field which will be added to all your work item types automatically.

Comment: After removing the “System.ExternalLinkCount” field references from the template and uploading it, I attempted to create a new project based on this process template. It then failed for a similar reason, this time round it was the turn of “System.NodeName” to cause havoc. I removed the references to it as well and that did the trick! Thanks @jessehouwing ,much appreciated! : )

I assumed this will also get added to all work item types automatically?