# TF400930: The reporting attribute is inconsistent between the imported XML and what is currently configured for the field

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-process-template

We've just upgraded from TFS 2015.2 to TFS 2017.3 and we're running in to an issue when creating new team projects.

For some reason, we're getting the following error in the error log when we try to create a new team project:

```
[09:54:24.797]   Importing work item types
[09:54:25.663]   [Error] TF400930: The reporting attribute for field Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate is inconsistent between the imported XML and what is currently configured for the field. Correct the field configuration in the XML and try again.
[09:54:25.667]   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.LegacyValidationException: TF400930: The reporting attribute for field Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate is inconsistent between the imported XML and what is currently configured for the field. Correct the field configuration in the XML and try again.
[09:54:25.667]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.ServerMetadataProvisioningHelper.ThrowValidationException(String message)
[09:54:25.667]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.Provision.UpdatePackageField.CheckDefinitionConsistency(XmlElement fieldElement)
[09:54:25.667]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.Provision.UpdatePackageField.Update(XmlElement fieldElement)
```

Here is the result from witadmin:

```
  Field: Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate
  Name: State Change Date
  Type: DateTime
  Use: --- (Bug, Shared Steps, Task, Test Case, User Story, Issue, Change Request)
  Indexed: False
  Reportable As: dimension
```

And from a search with Notepad++:
[Notepad++ Search for Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Eoyp.png)

As you can see from the search, it is being "reportable" as a dimension, which is what witadmin is saying the current attribute is.

Any idea on what we're doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you Configured features after the upgrade? If not please do that first.  Refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked on my side, by default the reportable attributes are not set in the Workitem definition files (.xml files).

So, please try to remove the attribute `reportable = "dimension"` from all the Wits. Then import the Wits and try it again.

If that still not work, you can try removing the `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate`definition from these work items, it's a standard field which will be added to all your work item types automatically.

Reference this similar thread : [Tfs project creation results in error: TF400930: Field 'System.ExternalLinkCount' is defined multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352075/tfs-project-creation-results-in-error-tf400930-field-system-externallinkcount)

Comment: It appears I'm getting the same error but on a different field (`System.Title`).  I tried removing the `reportable = "dimension"` attribute but i appear to get the same error